# Design query for following scenario

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables - Table1:

```
id  name  number
------------------
1   x1    123
2   x2    234
```

...and Table2:

```
tbl1id  title  rank
--------------------
1       t1      3
1       t2      2
2       t1      3
1       t3      1
```

Is there a way I can join them to return result as showing max title based on min rank for given user:

```
id  name  number  max_title  rank
----------------------------------
1   x1    123     't3'        1
2   x2    234     't1'        3
```

question updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT t.id,
          t.name,
          t.number,
          COALESCE(x.max_title, 'no title associated') AS max_title
     FROM TABLE1 t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.tbl1id,
                  MAX(t2.title) 'max_title'
             FROM TABLE2 t2
            WHERE t2.rank = (SELECT MIN(rank) 
                               FROM TABLE2 
                              WHERE tbl1id = t2.tbl1id)
         GROUP BY t2.tbl1id) x ON x.tbl1id = t.id
```

Comment: Sorry i updated question but you are right for my previous question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.number, MAX(t2.title)
FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.tbl1id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.number
```

**EDIT:**
- updated to use LEFT JOIN incase its the case there may not be a record in table2 for a given id.
- answer is now irrelevant as question has changed since the original one. Leaving for history.

Comment: There was no mention of what the real relationship was between these tables. But if there is the possiblity of no records in "table2" for an id, then just needs a LEFT JOIN instead.